# Execute Update on DropDownList change

Tags: c#, gridview, asp.net-3.5

At the moment, I have a GridView with the following in the ItemTemplate:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit">
    <asp:Label ID="Label6x" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("progress_full") %>' /></asp:LinkButton>
```

This works fine and when I click on it, it displays the EditTemplate which currently contains the following:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" 
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("progress") %>'>
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">In queue</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Being worked on</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Complete</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList><br />
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
```

How can I get the dropdown to automatically execute the `Update` command when it is changed, instantly returning back to the ItemTemplate, instead of me making the change to the DropDown and having to click `Update`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add `AutoPostBack="true"` to your DropDownList and set `OnSelecIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"`

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //execute here your update
   ......
}
```

Comment: The current `Update` LinkButton uses `OnRowUpdating` from the `GridView`.  In the `OnRowUpdating` function, I have a `GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];` which does not work if I copy the code into the `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` function.

Comment: You can iterate about your grid oshirowanen

Comment: foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
{                            
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
       
    }
}